Return Exact Match from the column based on the list of lookup values
I have a list of lookup values from Column I.
I have a set of different users from Cell A2:E2 but I want my output on G2 to show only Agent Joe since he is from my list of lookup values.


Will there ever be a time that there are more than one match per row?  If so, how should it be handled?

There might yes! If that happen, what would you suggest the best way to populate those multiple match in a row? And if that happen, I want to populate them in the same row

Use FILTER in TEXTJOIN to deal with multiple matches:
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A2:E2,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:E2,I:I,0))))



Works perfectly! But I am also considering what you've mentioned. How about if there's multiple match on that same row?

That's great! How about if I want them to spill in columns instead of showing them on a single cell?

Remove the TEXTJOIN wrapper and use just the FILTER, it will return a horizontal spill.
